# base64encode altchars in java

Tags: java, python, base64

What the java version of this python method?

http://docs.python.org/library/base64.html

base64.b64encode(s[, altchars])
Encode a string use Base64.

Optional altchars must be a string of at least length 2 (additional characters are ignored) which specifies an alternative alphabet for the + and / characters. This allows an application to e.g. generate URL or filesystem safe Base64 strings. The default is None, for which the standard Base64 alphabet is used.

..does java support altchars?

Comment: Yes, Java as a language supports such feature. Are you looking for a library that has this functionality implemented?

Answer (score 1):

Apache Commons, `Base64` has a constructor (and various static methods) for URL safe Base64 encoding:

[`Base64(int lineLength, byte[] lineSeparator, boolean urlSafe)`](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html#Base64%28int,%20byte%5b%5d,%20boolean%29)

> `urlSafe` - Instead of emitting '`+`' and '`/`' we emit '`-`' and '`_`' respectively. `urlSafe` is only applied to encode operations. Decoding seamlessly handles both modes.

Comment: .. the altchars is what I'm struggling with.  What's the java equivalent for that option?

Comment: What do you mean? In what way isn't the option I suggest usable?

Comment: what you posted here replaces + and / with - and _ ,however, the python code replaces + with _ and / with _ ...or am I missing something.  So I can do the replace after the initial encoding.. but though there was a better way.